# Can you run ssl with bottle + AD Authenticate?

Tags: python, mongodb, ssl, bottle

I have been looking at multiple sources and can't seem to get a good answer. I am trying to deploy a very simple app that displays information from a mongodb, accepts post data for input, uses SSL, and AD for Authentication.

I am using bottle with python 2.7, mongodb, on a windows 64-bit platform. I can switch to CentOS if that is completely necessary.

So far, none of the very few tutorials out there seem to work on my current configuration. Is what I'm asking for possible? Should I switch to a different framework?

**tldr:**

Can you run a bottle application with SSL and AD integration?

If not, what python framework would be nearly as easy and still have this functionality.

**edit:** I found [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/) for flask. Could it work with bottle? Also, can it be done on windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are definitely ways to accomplish your goal of having bottle use SSL + AD on windows.

SSL with bottle:

- https://github.com/nickbabcock/bottle-ssl
- http://dgtool.blogspot.com/2011/12/ssl-encryption-in-python-bottle.html
- [bottle on cherrypy server + ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10390927/bottle-on-cherrypy-server-ssl)

python with AD (as well as information on windows specifically):

- [Authenticating against active directory using python + ldap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140439/authenticating-against-active-directory-using-python-ldap)
- https://gist.github.com/ibeex/1288159

If you wanted to use session management for authentication you could pair the AD with bottle middleware such as beaker: [bottle hooks with beaker session middleware and checking logins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698473/bottle-hooks-with-beaker-session-middleware-and-checking-logins)

Bottle itself does not have built in abilities to deal with SSL that I know of like flask. But the last SSL link above shows similar simple useability.

Comment: So would you go with flask or make bottle work? I'm not too far into dev yet.

Comment: Personally I enjoy bottles "here's a web framework, add what you need" approach more than frameworks that tries to accomplish everything. I have actually had to work on a project that had to solve a very similar issue, and we used Pyramid (has LDAP support) + Nginx for SSL. It was honestly a nightmare. Another team had the same problem and used bottle + python-ldap + nginx and had great success. If you absolutely want the SSL native in the framework, I would go with flask. If you are ok with a custom design or using nginx, use bottle.

Comment: I'll try to use nginx then. Thanks for the tips.